# Database and sorting values by user preference

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Let's say I have a simple table like that:

```
unique ID | url | order
```

`unique ID` is given automatically as usualy, `url` is something that has to be submitted.
But how can I arrange orded?

I would like a user to be able to arrange those `url`s in an orded he wants.

How can I achieve that? That last inserted item has always the last order number and if I move item that has order number 5 to 1 all the items order numbers change. I want to implement it with some kind of drag and drop in JavaScript, but that's not really importat right now.

What I'm having problems with is the PHP side. To change the orded numbers.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem here, but if I'm a user and presented with a long list of URLs and order numbers, I'm unlikely to want to spend time dragging and dropping them into a particular order

Comment: url is just an example... you can imagine they are image for an example and you want to re-order them and save the same orded to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do exactly this, and it works fine. I use jQuery UI Sortable for the interface like this:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    function renumberSortables(){
        // Re-number the ordering i the list.

        $("ul.sortable").each(function(){
            $(this)
                .find("li")
                    .each(function(index){
                        $(this).find("input.ordering").val(index);
                    });
        });
    }

    $("ul.sortable").sortable({       
        opacity: 0.8,
        stop: renumberSortables
    }); 
}
```

html/php:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <?php foreach($sortables as $index => $sortable){ ?>
        <li>
            <input class="ordering" type="hidden" name="sortable[<?= $index ?>][ordering]" value="<?= $sortable.ordering ?>">

            (Your stuff here…)

        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have a dropdown or something which decides what order to display the data it would eitger be ascending or descending. Then in your SQL query end it with `ORDER BY url DESC` or `ORDER BY url ASC`

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this with sortable in jquery UI quite easily, it would give you an array of ids in order, from there it's just a case of doing a $.post to your php page which just iterates the array (therefore you know the order value) updates the row and sets the new order value.

Your stop function in jquery would look something like:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
        var ids = [];
        ui.item.parent().children().each(function(n, element) {
            ids[ids.length] = element.id;
        });

        $.post("/somelocation", {
            orderedids: ids.toString()
        } );
    }
```